# Can't Enable Always on Support for SSISDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-server, availability-group

I need to set up Always on Support for SSISDB and I am receiving this message:

The operation cannot be performed on database "SSISDB" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.

I Did have this set up no problem before, but we had to delete the Catalogue and recreate it. And once we have done this, it wont turn back on.

We have AG Set up for all of our other databases and trying to add SSISDB into the AG works but then says we need Always on Support turned on, and this is when we receive the error message.

Comment: Is it on-prem SQL or Azure? if it is Azure, what type of SQL Server, Standard, or MI?

Comment: Hi, It is Azure SQL Server and it's an Enterprise 2019

Answer (score 0):

> The operation cannot be performed on database "SSISDB" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.

As error suggest the cause can be mirroring session and the main database remains accessible when a mirroring session is paused or removed.

To Suspend mirroring session use following command:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE _database_name_ SET PARTNER SUSPEND
```

where *database_name* denotes the mirrored database whose active session you want to pause.

The mirror database no longer keeps up with the principal database when mirroring is pausing, which results in the principal database running exposed.

Also see, [Configure Integration Services Catalog Database SSISDB](https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-integration-services-catalog-database-ssisdb-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups/) by **Rajendra Gupta** for more information.

Comment: I've tried the code you gave and it is not involved in a mirroring session. It is involved in a AG but you have to add it to an AG to then turn on Always On Support.